# Character passing from C (clang) to fortran (gfortran) since Mac osx mojave

Tags: c, macos, gfortran

I have a piece of C++ code calling fortran code. It use to work until I updated to MacOsX 10.14 (Mojave). In fortran I have something like:

```
SUBROUTINE BLA(C)
CHARACTER*(*) C
PRINT*, C
END
```

and in C:

```
char c[128];
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   bla(c);
}
```

it now fails with:

```
h2root(41545,0x1116165c0) malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=140728898424832) failed (error code=3)
h2root(41545,0x1116165c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Memory allocation failure in xrealloc
```

(h2root is the name of my program).
It used to work without problem before OSX 10.14. Now, as soon as the string C is accessed on the fortran side I get this crash. Some ideas ?
I am using fortran 8.2.0